# Searching for #ifdef in a header file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
std::string systemStr = "C:\\gcc1\\gccxml.exe ";
    systemStr += "\"" ;
    systemStr += argv[1] ;
    std::cout<<"Header File is:"<<argv[1]<<endl;
```

In the above code snippet, argv[1] represents the name of the header file. I want to open this header file and search for #ifdefs that may be present. How do I go about doing this? The problem is that argv[1] is a string. I'm sorry if I'm unclear.

Comment: I'm sorry, argv is defined in main() like this: bool main(int argc, char *argv[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
std::cout<<"Header File is:"<<argv[1]<<endl;

std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
int lineNum = 0;
bool hasIfdef = false;

while( file.good() )
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline( file, line );
    lineNum++;

    if( line.find("#ifdef") != std::string::npos ||
        line.find("#ifndef") != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << "Line " << lineNum << ": " << line << std::endl;
        hasIfdef = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't parse your header file...  So if `#ifdef` appears inside a string, or the line is in a comment block or whatever it'll still be picked up.

Comment: You should also realize that there can be whitespace (though not a newline) between the `#` and the `ifdef`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with a shell script:

```
     cat header.h | grep -n "^[:space:]*#[:space:]*if[n]*def"
```

This will display the line number and #ifdef or #ifndef.

If you need to do this from within a C program you could always exec the shell script.